# xscreensaver not working after upgrade to 21.04

Tags: upgrade, lock-screen, 21.04, xscreensaver

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04 (using gnome).  When I run the command to startup the xscreensaver process I get the following:

```
xscreensaver: 16:32:30: locking is disabled (Cannot lock securely under Wayland).
```

When I attempt to lock the screen with `xscreensaver-command -lock`, I get the following:

```
xscreensaver-command: locking not enabled.
```

This all worked under 20.04, but does not under 21.04.  I'm not sure if this is something I did/didn't do, a limitation of 21.04, or some configuration change that I need to make.  What do I need to do to get this resolved?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, I think it is because Wayland is the default for user session. Logout then login with X session, see if it works there.

Comment: Switch to Xorg.

Comment: I'm not sure about either of these suggestions.  I'm not sure what you mean when you say login with X session or switch to Xorg.  How do I do these?  Thanks for the suggestions, so far.

Comment: @JonBelanger check this https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/01/ubuntu-21-04-will-use-wayland-by-default